# Disabling diagonal movement in Unity 5 2D? (using C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Or rather I should say, "EFFECTIVELY disabling diagonal movement".

There are plenty of Q/As online about this, but I keep encountering the same problem: When moving horizontally (left, for example), I can override the current direction and start moving vertically (by pushing up), which is what I want. But it does not work the other way around! Vertical movement can not override horizontal movement.

```
void Update () {

         float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
          ManageMovement(h, v); 
}    

void ManageMovement(float horizontal,float vertical) {

        if (vertical != 0f) {
                horizontal = 0f;
                Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (horizontal, vertical, 0);
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = movement * speed;
                return;
            } 

        if (horizontal != 0f) {
            vertical = 0f;
            Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (horizontal, vertical, 0);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = movement * speed;
            return;

        } else {
            Vector3 noMovement = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = noMovement;
        }
    }
```

If I reverse the order of these if() statements, it reverses the problem. So, that's a clue. But I'm not a great detective. I would love some help!

Answer (score 0):

Use Input.**[GetAxisRaw](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html)** instead of GetAxis.

GetAxis returns a float on a scale from -1 to 1. How quickly it returns to 0 depends on the axis settings. If you set gravity to a very high number, it will return to 0 more quickly. If you set sensitivity to a very high number, it will go to -1 or 1 more quickly.

So depending on these settings your function ManageMovement will be called multiple times with gradually changing values for horizontal and vertical.

The inputs over times could look something like this:

```
Update #1: ManageMovement(0.2, 1.0)
Update #2: ManageMovement(0.3, 0.9)
...
Update #N: ManageMovement(1.0, 0.0)
```

So when you check if vertical != 0, it will keep being non-zero until it has actually reached 0, and then for all those updates before that you set horizontal to 0.

GetAxisRaw is not smoothed in this way.

Comment: Oh my god! Yes! This is exactly it. I can't believe how simple that is, and very well explained. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ooh! Looks like I spoke a little too soon! The movement feels nice but it turns out I still can not go from moving horizontally to vertically. :/

Comment: You could try with a construct like `if (vertical > horizontal){...}else if(horizontal > vertical) {...} else {...}`. In general you don't want to compare floating values to exactly zero.

Comment: Sorry, you will of course need to do a Math.Abs around those values. Something like: if (Math.Abs(vertical) > Math.Abs(horizontal)){...}else if(Math.Abs(horizontal) > Math.Abs(vertical)) {...} else {...}.

Comment: I've reworked it to use `if (Mathf.Abs(horizontal) > Mathf.Abs(vertical)) {} 
else if (Mathf.Abs(vertical) > Mathf.Abs(horizontal)) {} else {}`.
I like the direction we're heading, but unfortunately now neither directions can override each other! As soon as two different keys are down, the player stops completely.

Comment: That is expected as you are entering the final else when they are equal. So what do you want to happen instead when both buttons are down? Continue in the current direction?

Comment: I want the new button press to override the old one, even if the old one is still being pressed. So if the player is moving left, then pushes up also, the sprite should move up. It's kind of hard to describe, but when you're using keys to control movement you can really feel the desire to have it happen.

Comment: I understand. I think you must then introduce a member variable to your class, so that you know what direction you where moving previously. So that you know you've changed directions. Because if both come in as '1' to your function and you don't keep any information about the previous direction you can't know that it has changed. I can try to update the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank you! I would really appreciate an example of what you mean. I am a pretty inexperienced programmer, and all the experience I do have is in Swift, which makes transitioning into other languages a little harder than usual I think.

Comment: Ok I'll try to get back to this later, but basically you must store variables for the direction and buttons that was used during the last function call, and you check those against the current values to determine what the new direction should be for you game logic. Unity has a good introduction video to member variables here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/variables-and-functions

Answer (score 0):

try to add else statement to ManageMovement method:

```
void ManageMovement(float horizontal,float vertical) {

    if (vertical != 0f) {
            horizontal = 0f;
            Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (horizontal, vertical, 0);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = movement * speed;
            return;
        } 

    else if (horizontal != 0f) {
        vertical = 0f;
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (horizontal, vertical, 0);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = movement * speed;
        return;

    } else {
        Vector3 noMovement = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = noMovement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi morlord, I added the *else* into the method and it doesn't appear to have changed anything.. Vertical movement is still dominant.